# embedding code from bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, embedding

[Code snippet from my blog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpf2U.jpg)
I am trying to embed code from bitbucket to my blog but the code snippet is getting displayed without any spaces and orientation. What to do?

`<script src="https://bitbucket.org/razatagarwal/gccprogrammer/src/80aad38fd88c6bee33ff04ff1d638b3bc9c0281b/mode.c?embed=t"></script>`

My Blog - http://gccprogrammer.blogspot.in/